# autocomplete feature - where to begin

Tags: solr, solr4

I have indexed the data from the db and so far it searches really well.
Now I want to create auto-complete/suggest feature in my website.
So far I have seen articles about Suggester, spellchecker, and searchComponents.
Can someone point me to a good article about basic autocomplete implementation?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the better articles I have seen on the different ways to implement autocomplete with Solr.

- [Different Ways to Make Auto Suggestions with Solr](http://blog.trifork.com/2012/02/15/different-ways-to-make-auto-suggestions-with-solr/)